Classifier Model Predictions, Imbalanced Data
I have 2 competing logistic regression models, with different sets of predictors. My task is to predict a binary variable (0/1), and I have a dataset with 5500 observations, only around 300 of which feature observations with value "1", meaning I have an imbalanced dataset without about 6% positive observations. My current understanding, is that I should use metrics from the confusion matrix (eg Accuracy, Specificity etc)and AUC-ROC on the test set (split 90/10) to see which model is better.
The main question I have is : What is the best way to predict my binary variable with these models? The most common approach I found is to set a threshold at 50%, but then the issue is that (as shown in the confusion matrix) my accuracy is lower than a basic strategy of always guessing "0", and the specificity is really low as well, over all this seems to suggest that I should use a different threshold, however I do not know how to determine the optimal threshold (and even then there seems to be a risk of overfitting).
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you very much.

Don't use accuracy, precision, recall, sensitivity, specificity, or the F1 score. Every criticism at the following threads applies equally to all of these, and indeed to all evaluation metrics that rely on hard classifications:
Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?
Is accuracy an improper scoring rule in a binary classification setting?
Classification probability threshold

Instead, use probabilistic classifications, and evaluate these using proper scoring rules.
This Meta.CV thread contains a curated list of useful links on imbalanced data.
